# Regex quantifiers - as many between two characters

Tags: regex, string, delimiter, quantifiers

I'm trying to find all the text between two characters but sometimes the string contains the delimiter character.

For example, If I use

```
(.*?)=(.*?),*
```

On the following string:

```
color=blue,weight=100kg,
```

It will result in:

```
match #1: color=blue
match #2: weight=100kg
```

However, if I have the following string:

```
color=blue,red,weight=100kg,
```

It will result in:

```
match #1: color=blue
match #2: red,weight=100kg
```

How can I make the regex return the following? (cutting the string at the last occurrence of the comma character)

```
match #1: color=blue,red
match #2: weight=100kg
```

Please note that the amount of colors separated by a comma could be more than 3, or none at all.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: instead of using the dot to describe the key, use a character class that excludes the comma (and the equal sign too).

Comment: What language/environment should the regex be suitable for?  How are you implementing this pattern.  We need a language tag on the question. @Haddock

Comment: @mickmackusa The question has been answered 2 years ago, but thanks for your interest! You can use regex in several environments and languages. My question is Regex syntax centered and independent from any programming language.

Comment: It's a rather unfortunate string that you are trying to parse.  When values can contain the delimiting character, it's time to revisit the data structure.

Comment: Is your sample text the whole string? or is the text a substring of a greater portion of text?  Can a splitting function call do?  How can your input vary?  Are there ever more than two substrings?  ever less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use this regex:

`[^,]+=[^=]+(?=,)` where

`[^,]+` - parameter name

`[^=]+(?=,)` - this will capture parameter value, that allowed to contain everything, but `=` symbol and should ends with comma.

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/dJlKNn/1)

Comment: so `([^,]+=[^=]+(?=,)),(.*)`

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with negated character classes a bit, you should be able to match it with

```
[^=,]+=(?:[^=,]+|,(?![^,=]+=))+
```

This matches

- `[^=,]+` everything that's not a comma or `=`
- `=` the following `=`
- `(?:[^=,]+|,(?=[^,=]+,))+` everything that's not a comma or a comma that is not followed directly by `=` with no toher comma in between - repeated as often as possible

See https://regex101.com/r/p8Bz9o/1

Answer (score 0):

Semantics: If we are dealing with the whole input string, then *matching* isn't the task, *splitting* is.

This makes the pattern even simpler.  `~,(?=[^,]+=)~` You need to match the a comma (consume it) that is followed by non-commas then an equals sign.  The lookahead does the necessary work and the *true* delimiting commas are destroyed in the process.

Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/hwQyhl/1

A PHP implementation: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ko2Mf))

```
$input = 'color=blue,red,weight=100kg,another=one,two,three,four,okay=enough,';

var_export(preg_split('~,(?=[^,]+=)~', rtrim($input, ','), 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'color=blue,red',
  1 => 'weight=100kg',
  2 => 'another=one,two,three,four',
  3 => 'okay=enough',
)
```